# Running external script from Java application on OS X

Tags: java, macos, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I'm having real issues getting an external script to run from my Java application on OS X 10.8.  It works on Windows, so not sure what I'm doing wrong for OS X.

What works (Windows):

```
String[] commands = {
    "\"" + _appDataDir + "\\Temp\\Workers\\" + _batchName + "\"", 
    "\"" + _appDataDir + "\\Temp\\frame%d.jpg\"", 
    "\"" + _fileName + "\""};
proc = rt.exec(commands);
```

So I have the following for OS X:

```
String[] commands = {
    _appDataDir + "/Temp/Workers/" + _batchName,
_appDataDir + "/Temp/Workers/mac-ffmpeg",   
_appDataDir + "/Temp/frame%d.jpg", 
"\"" + _fileName + "\""};
proc = rt.exec(commands);
```

This works when there are no spaces in the filename, but fails when there are spaces with a "java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor" error.

At the moment, I've changed all the paths to have no spaces as an easy fix, but I don't have control over the fileName string as this is selected by the user from a save dialog.  I've tried with and without double quotes around fileName but neither make any difference.

I also tried ProcessBuilder as below (both with and without the "/bin/bash/, -c" bits):

```
ProcessBuilder proc2 = new ProcessBuilder(
    "/bin/bash",
"-c",
_appDataDir + "/Temp/Workers/" + _batchName,
_appDataDir + "/Temp/Workers/mac-ffmpeg",
_appDataDir + "/Temp/frame%d.jpg",
"\"" + _fileName + "\""
);
proc = proc2.start();
```

but this gives the same error.  As far as I can tell I'm doing everything that's being suggested in other similar questions, but nothing is working.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the quotes around `"\"" + _fileName + "\""`, just a plain `_fileName` would work here.  When you provide an array to `Runtime.exec` (or to `ProcessBuilder`) you've already split your command up into "words" - if you add the quotes you're telling it to look for a file whose name is actually double-quote + `_fileName` + double-quote rather than just `_fileName`.

The real problem is likely to lie within the `_batchName` program, which presumably is a shell script that does the real work by calling other programs.  Within that script you will receive the `mac-ffmpeg`, `frame%d.jpg` and `_fileName` arguments as `$1`, `$2` and `$3`, and you need to make sure that they are properly quoted *within the script*, e.g. if the script currently says something like

```
processFile $3
```

then you need to change it to say

```
processFile "$3"
```

if it is to cope with file names that contain spaces.  Or if it is set up to handle multiple files at once:

```
processFiles $*
```

then you need to replace that with

```
processFiles "$@"
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Using quotes in the script itself has done the trick.  What threw me here was that when I tried running the script and passing the arguments (with double quotes) from Terminal it worked fine, so I had assumed the issue lay with the Java code rather than the script.